# Call exe with input file from mvc application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exe

I am calling an exe program, when invoked requires inputfile.txt and its generates outputfile.txt in same folder. exe is working fine.

Now I want to convert same thing in web application but there I am getting issues.

Code I am using is as below

```
// Prepare the process to run
           ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo();
           // Enter in the command line arguments, everything you would enter after the executable name itself
           start.Arguments = @"C:\Program Files\AET_Calculator\application\InputFile.txt"; ;
           // Enter the executable to run, including the complete path
           start.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\AET_Calculator\application\AET_Calculator.exe";
           // Do you want to show a console window?
           start.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
           start.Verb = "runas";
           start.UseShellExecute = true;
           int exitCode;


           // Run the external process & wait for it to finish
           using (Process proc = Process.Start(start))
           {
               proc.WaitForExit();

               // Retrieve the app's exit code
               exitCode = proc.ExitCode;
           }
```

Its throwing error. How can I call exe from web application passing input txt file

Here is error I am getting :
[image]

Comment: Can you be more precise? What error is it throwing?

Comment: `but there I am getting issues.` What issues **exactly**?

Comment: I have updated question with error

Answer (score 1):

You need to **grant execute access** on the `.exe` file to the user in `IIS` is going to use to access the file, most of the time app pool identity or in `IIS`  the `IIS_WPG` user.

Comment: I tried to create console application with same code and there also I am getting same issue